# ROR 3: working with environments and gems/bundler groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

Please could some one explain me how to work with different groups of gems in gemfile.

I've got the situaltion:
In my production enviroment i need some gems:

```
    group :production do
         gem 'pg'
    end
```

and I DON'T NEED this gems to be installed on my dev machine.
But when I run in command line come commandes "rails g.." it tries to check gemfile and says

**Could not find gem 'pg...**

How this situation should be handled?

Answer (score 0):

From http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

> therubyracer
>
> If you were previously using therubyracer or therubyracer-heroku,
>   these gems are no longer required and strongly discouraged as these
>   gems use a very large amount of memory.

Comment: ok, thanks, of notice! I'll remove it! but I steel have got the conceptual question about how to work with multiple eviroments and gem/bundler groups in gemfile.

Comment: Using the production group as you have in the example you gave is the correct usage.

Comment: But I can not run commands in the command line on my dev machine until I install pg gem, but I don't need it there. I need it on heorku. Do I really need to install it on dev machine??

Comment: Those command line commands are in development env by default. Try running `bundle exec rails g migrate`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4492/discussion-between-whitecolor-and-ctcherry)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be fixed after run "bundle install --without production"!!!